# How to use Fileupload in django?

Tags: python, django

Im new in django , When im learning django from documentation .i tried to make api using serializers and Function Based views .the this shows type object 'Questions' has no attribute 'objects'
`models.py`

```
class Questions:
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    status = models.CharField(default='inactive', max_length=30)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`serializers.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from demoapp.models import Questions


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Questions
        fields = (
            'id',
            'title',
            'description',
            'created_by',

        )
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from demoapp.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('poll', demoapp),
]
```

And Error is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Oj5q.png)

Comment: Can you show your `views.py` ?

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from demoapp.models import Questions
from demoapp.serializers import QuestionSerializer
from django.http import JsonResponse

def demoapp(request):
 if request.method=="GET":
  queryset=Questions.objects.all()
  serializer=QuestionSerializer(snippets)
  return JsonResponse(serializer.data,safe=False)

Comment: Add it to question, Its not readable :(